# GitHub Copilot extension on VS 2022

Tags: github-copilot

I have installed the copilot on my VS 2022 successfully (**My work laptop**). I also have paid an annual fee. but when I log in and activate it (paste the code and the message 'Congratulations, you're all set! Your device is now connected.' shown on the browser ) I only can see the below message in VS, copilot output tab

*'14:14:36:648  Please open https://github.com/login/device and enter the device activation code AD05-A79D that has been copied to the clipboard.'*

It seems to be stopped in this step and I can't activate it! any log to check? Any advice to fix it
Note: I have installed it on the same version of VS on my personal laptop.
Note: No filter from the IT side on the GitHub connection
Thanks for your advice :)

Comment: the activation code should be copied to the clipboard ready to be pasted into https://github.com/login/device